# TypeError: is not a function for the inheriting object function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I am just trying to understand prototypical inheritance using simple code.

```
function Place() {

}

Place.prototype.airportCode = function(code) {
    console.log('Airport code is: ' + code);
}

function City(cityName) {
    this.name = cityName;
}

City.prototype.railwayStateCode = function(code) {
    console.log('Railway station code is: ' + code);
}

City.prototype = Object.create(Place.prototype);

const sydney = new City('Sydney');

const melbourne = new Place();
```

When I try to

```
sydney.railwayStateCode('SYD');
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: sydney.railwayStateCode is not a function
```

As per my understanding, it should not throw an error. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overriding the prototype here:

```js
City.prototype = Object.create(Place.prototype);
```

To make it work change the order like this:

```js
City.prototype = Object.create(Place.prototype);

City.prototype.railwayStateCode = function(code) {
    console.log('Railway station code is: ' + code);
}
```